# Why doesn't my difference amplifier get saturated in LTSpice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, current-measurement, high-current

I'm currently simulating my high- side current sense amplifier for measuring mains current(along with the LP filter) .I also have the voltage sensing in the corner and I have attempted to simulate a realistic mains current magnitude of 15 A with a source and load impedance to avoid reflections.

I'm not sure why signal appears clipped even though the measured signal magnitude is less than the power supply range. How do I fix this? Is this getting saturated due to the high voltage in reference to ground?

**Difference Amplifier**

[image: Difference amplifier]

**Whole schematic**

[image: Schematic]

**Signal through current sense resistor(green) vs output of difference amplifier**
[image: Signals]

Comment: If you plot the current through `R3` and `R15` what do you get? Also, the `S` pin is shutdown`, not ground. It should be connected to either Vcc or Vee.

Comment: *"Is this getting saturated due to the high voltage in reference to ground?"* It will destroy the real opamp. Could you please explain why the load is split in two resistors and why low side sensing is not an option?

Comment: @devnull The resistors are to reduce the mains voltage to a level that the ADC can take in. 
Regarding the low side sensing, I've read that high side sensing is better for accuracy and fault detection which is why I chose it. Plus, low side sensing causes ground looping.

Though the op amp I'm planning to use is OPA2960ID which has a relative high CMRR? In your opinion, will the trade-off for accuracy be that much of a difference or can it be compensated by op amp with high CMRR ... if I were to use low side sensing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put some voltage numbers on your front end and you'll see that things have gone wrong: -

[image]

And... the circuit will fry.

You need to rethink how you are going to achieve this and I would recommend low-side monitoring.

Comment: Might be worth noting, there *are* some comparators and in-amps that can handle voltages higher than their rails, but I've never seen an op-amp that can.

Comment: @Andy aka  Echoing my comment I've read that high side sensing is better for accuracy and fault detection which is why I chose it. Plus, low side sensing causes ground looping. Though the op amp I'm planning to use is OPA2960ID which has a relative high CMRR. In your opinion, will the trade-off for accuracy be that much of a difference or can it be compensated by op amp with high CMRR ... if I were to use low side sensing?

Comment: @hellowurf what comment are you echoing? Low side sensing is simpler and ground loops can certainly be avoided.

Comment: @I meant to say it's been repeated in my question's comment section. What are the ways to avoid ground looping?

Comment: @hellowurf you adopt star-pointing of tracking to avoid ground loops. Or, you adopt isolation techniques such as using an isolated current sense device.

Answer (score 1):

Although the differential mode input is within +/- 5V, your *common mode* input is not. Hence the incorrect output.

You need to reduce the common mode input at the op-amp. Since R3 and R17 form a voltage divider, as do R15 and R14, you need to adjust the ratios so that the common mode voltage at the op-amp is within spec.